# How can I convert Wikitext Markup containing the double curly bracket functions, into plaintext or html?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, markup, wikipedia, wikitext

I am creating a customized Wiki Markup parser/interpreter. There is a big task however in regards to interpreting functions like these:

```
{{convert|500|ft|m|0}}
```

which is converted like so:

```
500 feet (152 m)
```

I'd like to avoid having to manually code interpretations of these functions, and would rather employ a method where I query a string

```
+akiva@akiva-ThinkPad-X230:~$ wiki-to-text "convert|3|to(-)|6|ft|abbr=on}}"
```

and get a return of:

```
"3 to 6 ft (0.91–1.83 m)"
```

Is there a tool to do this? Offline is by far the most ideal solution, but I could live with having to query a server.

Comment: Best way to parse locally: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:TemplateData

Comment: @JohnStrood Hmmm... Interesting. On my end, I have a local mediawiki, and ended up programming my own parser that can do varied types of interpretations. https://git.launchpad.net/qconsoledesigner/tree/qmediawiki.cpp if you are interested in a local implementation. (Although it is admittedly catered specifically for my purposes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could query the [MediaWiki api](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) to get a parsed text from wikitext. E.g. to parse the template Template:Done from the english wikipedia you could use: [`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text={{Template:done}}&title=Test`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%7B%7BTemplate:done%7D%7D&title=Test) (see the [online docs for parse](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse)). You, however, need a MediaWiki instance that provides a template that you want to parse and which works in the exact same way. If you install a webserver locally, you can install your own MediaWiki instance and parse wikitext locally, too.

Btw.: There's the [Parsoid project](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid), too, which implements a node-based wikitext->html->wikitext parser. However, it, iirc, still needs to query the api of the wiki to parse templates.